# Adding icon on the left side of the JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

How to add an icon on the left side of `JTabbedPane` while using `JPanel` as the component of
`JTabbedPane`?

As I know how to add icon on the left side of the `JTabbedPane` while using `JLabel` but
don't know what to do in case of `JPanel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean the `JTabbedPane`'s tab component.  If you are using a `JPanel`, you will need to add a `JLabel` to the panel and apply an appropriate layout manager to position the elements the way you want them

There is an example in the [How to Use Tabbed Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html) under the section **Tabs With Custom Components**, it does add a `JButton` to the right hand side, but I'm sure you can figure out how to switch to a `JLabel` on the left side...